# Changing the Order of elements in a Stack so that all Odd numbers go before Even numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, stack

I am looking for a way to change the order of the elements in a Stack, so that the *even numbers* go after *odd numbers*.

For example, the following stack:

```
5, 2, 6, 7, 1, 4, 3
```

Becomes:

```
5, 7, 1, 3, 2, 6, 4
```

[image]

Here is my current code. I'm stuck on finding out how to change the order :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Stack<Integer> p = new Stack<>();

    p.push(3);
    p.push(4);
    p.push(1);
    p.push(7);
    p.push(6);
    p.push(2);
    p.push(5);
    
    ListIterator<Integer> ListIterator = p.listIterator(p.size());  
     
    while (ListIterator.hasPrevious())  {  
        Integer i = ListIterator.previous();  
        System.out.println(i);  
    } 
}
```

Comment: Looks like your code only builds the initial stack of numbers.  Here's a hint:  you need to separate the even and the odd and then put them into a stack.  The stack would have one half of odd numbers and the other half even numbers.

Comment: Looks like you need to sort the stack, but the requirement is unclear. What happens if both numbers are odd, do we keep them in encounter order, or smaller comes first(natural order), something else? Same question about even numbers. And since you actually need to sort, it's questionable if `Stack` is the best data structure. Perhaps `PriorityQueue` or `ArrayList` would be more appropriate?

Comment: @Chaosfire based on the input and expected output in the question, the odds and the even numbers must be in they appeared in the original stack.  For example, if the original stack contains 1,2,3,4,5 then the updated stack would be 1,3,5,2,4.

Comment: Do you care about the order of the elements? For example, would a result of `[1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6]` be OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish the task of separating *odd* and *even* elements.

I suspect that the purpose of this challenge is getting familiar with the [Stack data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) and its basic operations.

So here's a solution which utilizes two additional Stacks, one to accumulate the odd elements, another for storing even elements.

The initial stack is being empty out and its elements are being distributed between two other stacks. Now have odd and even numbers separated, and the only thing left is to join the data.

The time complexity of this solution is linear **O(n)**. It is **more performant** than sorting the data, which would have a linear-logarithmic time complexity **O(n log n)**.

That how it can be implemented:

```
Stack<Integer> numbers = new Stack<>();
        
numbers.push(3);
numbers.push(4);
numbers.push(1);
numbers.push(7);
numbers.push(6);
numbers.push(2);
numbers.push(5);
        
Stack<Integer> odd = new Stack<>();
Stack<Integer> even = new Stack<>();
        
while (!numbers.isEmpty()) {
    Integer next = numbers.pop();
    if (next % 2 == 0) even.push(next);
    else odd.push(next);
}
        
numbers.addAll(odd);
numbers.addAll(even);
    
System.out.println(numbers);
```

*Output:*

```
[5, 7, 1, 3, 2, 6, 4]
```

***Note:***

- Class `Stack` is legacy, and shouldn't be used (unless it's a requirement of your assignment). When you need an implementation of the stack data structure in Java the recommended alternative is to use implementations of the [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html) interface.
- Try to use more meaningful names than `p`. It's a good habit because it makes the code easier to read and maintain. Single-letter variable are acceptable only rare cases, like variables defined within a `for`-loop. Also see [Java Language Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Comment: Thank you for your help ! It is more clear for me now :)

Answer (score 0):

`Stack` is subclass of `AbstractList`, so you can use [List.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) by providing custom [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

```
public class Temp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<Integer> p = new Stack<>();

        p.push(3);
        p.push(4);
        p.push(1);
        p.push(7);
        p.push(6);
        p.push(2);
        p.push(5);

        p.sort((a, b) -> {
            if (a % 2 == 0 && b % 2 == 0) {
                return 0;
            }
            if (a % 2 == 0) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (b % 2 == 0) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        });
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}
```

For the initial stack of - `[3, 4, 1, 7, 6, 2, 5]` this results in - `[3, 1, 7, 5, 4, 6, 2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the negated (so `1` orders before `0`) difference between modulo 2:

```java
p.sort((a, b) -> b % 2 - a % 2);
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/MK0jYl).

Answer (score 0):

Using the JDK implementation of `Stack` can be hard to reason about if you use `iterator()` or `stream()`, as the `Iterator` and `Spliterator` implementations are define in `Vector` which `Stack` inherits from. So calling methods like `System.out.println(stack)` will not be the same as printing all of the elements one by one by popping them off the stack. The following code illustrates this difference. Since `Stack` inherits from `Vector` in the JDK, I will use a `Stream` with `partitioningBy` to separate the evens and odds with a `Predicate` (`i -> i % 2 == 0`), and then push both lists onto a result `Stack`.

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();

stack.push(3);
stack.push(4);
stack.push(1);
stack.push(7);
stack.push(6);
stack.push(2);
stack.push(5);

Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> partitions =
        stack.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(i -> i % 2 == 0));

Stack<Integer> result = new Stack<>();
partitions.get(true).forEach(result::push);
partitions.get(false).forEach(result::push);

System.out.println(result);
while (!result.isEmpty())
{
    System.out.print(result.pop() + (result.isEmpty() ? "" : ", "));
}
```

*Output:*

```
[4, 6, 2, 3, 1, 7, 5]  // The System.out.println(result)
5, 7, 1, 3, 2, 6, 4    // The loop printing each call to pop
```

Using a `sort` approach with a `Stack` is interesting. The method `sort` is also defined in `Vector` and sorts the backing array calling `Arrays.sort()`. As others have already provided solutions using `sort`, I won't provide any here.

It may be useful to look at a different Stack implementation to learn different approaches. The following code shows how to solve this problem using a `MutableStack<Integer>` from [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections). The iteration order in Eclipse Collections matches the LIFO approach you would expect when popping elements off of a stack. I'm using the `partition` method available on `MutableStack` which returns a `PartitionMutableStack` with selected and rejected elements based on the `Predicate`. There are convenient factory methods available on the `Stacks` class for creating stacks, which is very useful for writing tests.

```
MutableStack<Integer> stack = Stacks.mutable.with(3, 4, 1, 7, 6, 2, 5);
PartitionMutableStack<Integer> partition = stack.partition(i -> i % 2 == 0);
MutableStack<Integer> result =
        Stacks.mutable.withAllReversed(partition.getRejected().asLazy()
                .concatenate(partition.getSelected().asLazy()));

Assertions.assertEquals(Stacks.mutable.with(4, 6, 2, 3, 1, 7, 5), result);

System.out.println(result);
while (!result.isEmpty())
{
    System.out.print(result.pop() + (result.isEmpty() ? "" : ", "));
}
```

*Output:*

```
[5, 7, 1, 3, 2, 6, 4]  // The System.out.println(result)
5, 7, 1, 3, 2, 6, 4    // The loop printing each call to pop
```

There are also primitive stacks available in Eclipse Collections, that have no equivalent in the JDK. These are helpful if you care about the impact of boxing primitive values like `int` as `Integer` objects. The following code shows how to solve this problem using a `MutableIntStack` in Eclipse Collections. There is no `partition` method available today on primitive stacks but this could always be contributed by someone as an open source contribution if they find it useful enough. I use `reject` and `select` to filter out first odds, and then evens. This will result in two iterations over stack, unlike `partition` which results in one iteration. I use the same list to hold the results of `reject` and `select` to push onto the result Stack.

```
MutableIntStack stack = IntStacks.mutable.with(3, 4, 1, 7, 6, 2, 5);
MutableIntList list = stack.reject(i -> i % 2 == 0, IntLists.mutable.empty());
MutableIntStack result = IntStacks.mutable.withAllReversed(
        stack.select(i -> i % 2 == 0, list));

Assertions.assertEquals(IntStacks.mutable.with(4, 6, 2, 3, 1, 7, 5), result);

System.out.println(result);
while (!result.isEmpty())
{
    System.out.print(result.pop() + (result.isEmpty() ? "" : ", "));
}
```

*Output:*

```
[5, 7, 1, 3, 2, 6, 4]   // The System.out.println(result)
5, 7, 1, 3, 2, 6, 4     // The loop printing each call to pop
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.